# Change Atom's "git diff" package theme to Github theme

Tags: atom-editor, git-diff

The default theme for Atom's Git Diff package is,

[image]
It shows the changes in `dark green`, deleted lines in `dark red` and has a `black` background.

Is there a way to show the difference as shown in the Github console as show in the image below.
[image]

I tried adding the code below to the `styles.less` file but that does not highlight the modified text and does not modify the colour in the unstaged changes but modifies the colour while working on the file.(please refer to image below the code)

```
atom-text-editor .gutter .line-number {
&[class*="git"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
}

&.git-line-added {
    background-color: rgba(168, 255, 96, 0.6);
}

&.git-line-modified {
    background-color: rgba(233, 192, 98, 0.6);
}

&.git-line-removed {
    background-color: rgba(204, 102, 102, 0.6);
}}
```

[image]